# Fixing 403 Access Denied Errors When Hosting a React Router App in AWS S3 with CloudFlare

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I have a React App that is deployed on an S3 bucket.

When deploying a React Router app to S3, going directly to a React route will produce a 403 Access Denied error because S3 will try to look for an object in the bucket at that path.

Right now, we are redirecting all traffic to the index.html file, all the routes load fine, but first, we are receiving a 403 response, before the page loads. Which is causing a headache for Search Engines and SEO.

This can be solved by creating a custom error response in CloudFront that handles the HTTP 403 Response by responding with the index page and a 200 OK.

We are using Cloudflare as our CDN and switching to cloudfront at this point is not an option.

Is there a way to solve this problem using CloudFlare or S3 Configuration settings?

Comment: Did you enable static website hosting and input index.html for the default page?

Comment: @jordanm I did.

Comment: A 403 doesn't redirect, so there is something really off about your setup. Is accessing index.html not actually working at all and you have set index.html as the custom error page?

Comment: Yes. that is correct. All roads lead back to index.html.

Comment: Perhaps you could explore hosting your React application on Cloudflare directly? See https://pages.cloudflare.com

Comment: I ended up solving with a cloudflare worker.